# How to enable CORS? Sever? Javascript? where?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors, axios

right now I am testing my reactjs site on locahost:3333 and my asp.net web api 2 on localhost:54690.

I am using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for my ajax but when I make a request I get an error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54690/api/Storage/Get.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3333' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I tried to add Cors but guess I am not doing it right. I tried server side and client side.

```
   var instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'http://localhost:54690/api',
            timeout: 1000,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
        });

        instance.get('/Storage/Get')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

server side

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3333/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class StorageController : ApiController
```

WebapiConfig.

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new EnableQueryAttribute());

            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableCors();
        }
    }
```

Edit

Seems like when I do this

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

it works. I dont' even need to put anything in my header for my ajax. Though this not really a soultion as I don't want this to happen in production I am guessing?

Also is there a global function I can setup cors at? Kinda sucks to put it on every controller.

Edit 2

looking more into the link from @kormali_2 I see that the problem might be because I have "http://locahost:3333/" where it should be "http://locahost:3333" also there is a global option I can use.

Comment: Did you `using System.Web.Http.Cors;` ? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Yes for my controller i have using System.Web.Http.Cors;

Comment: adding cors headers request-side makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable CORS globally with this:

```
// Enable CORS globally for any host
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

To enable it just for a specific host you would use:

```
// Enable CORS globally for specific host
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3333", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

More information at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:54690/api',
        timeout: 1000,
        headers: { 
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    });
```

Comment: this answer makes no sense. said header doesn't belong on the request-side of the equation.